# Как изменить размер canvas?

Tags: html, css, canvas

Есть canvas, которому я задаю размер

```
<canvas id='my_canvas' height=300px width=400px>Reload page</canvas>
```

После этого загружаю в него картинку и обрезаю ее (не совсем обрезаю, но отображаю часть)

```
ctx.drawImage(pic,position,0,size,size,0,0,size,size);
```

как я могу изменить размер canvas после "обрезки" изображения ? если через код прописывать-ничего не меняется

```
canvas.width=position;
canvas.height=position;
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
canvas.width  = 500;
canvas.height = 400; 
canvas.style.width  = '1000px';
canvas.style.height = '800px';
```

Comment: большое спасибо, помогло